# Есть ли возможность массив на стеке передать в параметры метода?

Tags: c#, .net

stackalloc выделяет память под массив на стеке, но она имеет жесткие ограничения, в частности нельзя освободить память до выхода из метода, нельзя указатель на массив объявить полем класса, нельзя указатель на массив передать в параметры метода.

Вопрос: есть ли другой способ выделить память под массив на стеке, передавать его в параметры метода, объявлять его полем класса?

p.s. подойдёт даже экспериментальный вариант, видел, например, что удавалось даже классы инициализировать на стеке при помощи изменения самой платформы.

Comment: Ну вот выделили вы память на стеке, присвоили адрес полю класса, вышли из метода - стек удалился. На что указывает поле?

Comment: Возможно, вам нужен [fixed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/zycewsya.aspx) буфер.

Comment: А зачем вам stackalloc, позвольте поинтересоваться?

Comment: @VladD, а зачем разработчики добавили в шара стекаллок? Для выделения памяти на стеке, а не в куче.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, в целом конечно неплохой вариант, если конечно они действительно выделяются на стеке, но заводить структуру под них не очень резонно. Есть ли другие варианты?. По поводу того что стек удаляется при выходе из метода - так сделали разработчики, за каким .... - непонятно.

Comment: @user222250: Он нужен в каких-то редких случаях interop'а, ну и для экстремальной оптимизации, которая обычно не нужна. Для чего вам это? Может быть, вы просто решаете задачу, для которой C# — неподходящий инструмент?

Comment: @VladD , для экспериментальных оптимизаций, в вопросе косвенно указал это

Comment: @user222250: Если вы делаете экстремальные оптимизации, ну так переходите на ассемблер, зачем вам C# тогда? Уж на ассемблере можно что угодно выделять где угодно.

Comment: @VladD, почитайте на досуге: http://aakinshin.net/ru/blog/ Подобными микрооптимизациями занимается много народу. Разве Вам самому не интересно?) Linq Вас разбаловал)))

Comment: @Align: Мне кажется, что такой высокоуровневый язык, как C#, не предназначен для низкоуровневых трюков. То, что на нём _можно_ делать какие-то низкоуровневые трюки вовсе не означает, что они нужны или уместны в этом языке. Если код выделяет память на стеке, использует адресную арифметику, занимается преобразованием типов из байтового буфера в структуры данных, его нужно просто переписать на более подходящем языке. C# хорош для своих целей.

Comment: @VladD, не воспринимайте это как что-то неправильное. Отнесите это к спортивной тематике. Слышал даже про сообщества, которые занимаются тем, что оптимизируют один и тот же метод. Это простой спортивный интерес. Приведу цитату с одной видеоконференции "мой коллега недавно похвалился, что увеличил производительность своего метода в 1000 раз, вопрос - как этот метод был написан до этого?". Подобные вещи в первую очередь нацелены на получения знаний, всем программистам приятно когда их код работает быстрее номинального варианта, это учит грамотному подходу в написании будущих функций.

Comment: @Align: С спортивной трактовкой согласен, конечно. Поставить язык с ног на голову всегда интересно. То есть если это не промышленный код, задающийся целью оптимизации путём низкоуровневых трюков вместо применения правильных алгоритмов, а просто интересный трюк, я только за.

Comment: @VladD, в продакшн-коде врятли кто-то будет использовать подобное, иначе имеет риск поиметь себе сильную головную боль в дальнейшем. Поведение будущих версий CLR и JIT - не предугадать. Но в качестве самообразования и спортивного интереса - вполне себе интересная тема.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю, на уровне языка это невозможно.

Дело в том, что C# — безопасный язык. В отличие от языков наподобие C и С++, в которых вы можете делать что угодно, и получать висящие указатели, C# не даст вам сделать этого. (Результатом этого является, например, невозможность атак срыва стека на .NET-приложения.)

Если бы было возможно выделить память на стеке, и запомнить указатель на неё в поле класса, то этот объект смог бы пережить фрейм стека, на который он ссылается, и при этом вы получили бы доступ к чужой памяти. Такого безопасный язык позволить не имеет права.

Окей, вы можете обойти ограничения языка, и превратить его в C, используя unsafe-контекст. В unsafe-контексте таки можно закастить указатель в `IntPtr` и сохранить в таком виде в класс.

```
class UnsafeContainer
{
    public IntPtr data;
}

class Program
{
    static UnsafeContainer container;
    static unsafe void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int* addr = stackalloc int[100];
        container = new UnsafeContainer { data = (IntPtr)addr };
    }
}
```

При таком кодировании вы теряете все преимущества безопасного языка, и приобретаете такое же undefined behaviour, как и в C++. Надеюсь, что вам реально это **очень** нужно. При малейшей ошибке в unsafe-коде ожидайте проблем в совершенно несвязанных местах, как обычно бывает при UB.

Comment: Спасибо, все гениальное - просто. Мне даже в голову не пришло скастовать с IntPtr. Повторюсь - код только для спортивного интереса.

Comment: @Align: Я помню, последний абзац ответа скорее для будущих читателей.

Comment: @Align: Пожалуйста, рад, что помогло.